# Weight Painting System Problems

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

In regards to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72568/problem-with-weight-painting) he wants to create a steady falloff using weight painting with one bone but according to the way that blender's weight painting system this is not possible. I understand why that is, but that means that with one or two bone armatures it is incredibly difficult if not impossible to do detailed weight painting with the current system. Are there any workarounds for these kinds of problems or is this just a problem with the current weight painting system?

Comment: Hi, sorry but can you detail a bit what is your specific problem, maybe with an example? Most people can (learn to) paint weigths in blender and do amazing characters, so maybe it is not "broken" as you say, but just a different system froma what you're used to (just wondering)?

Comment: also, have you tried b-bones?

Comment: no, is there a difference besides the look of them?

Comment: also this question:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/25933/my-weight-painting-only-works-at-100-no-matter-the-shade?rq=1